# JavaScript - Find row's first cell value when clicked

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following table where each row has 4 cells with a button on the last cell:

```
<table class='Table1'>
     <tr>
        <td>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>
            DEF
        </td>
        <td>
            GHI
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='return'>return</button>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            JKL
        </td>
        <td>
            MNO
        </td>
        <td>
            PQR
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='return'>return</button>
        </td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

When the button is clicked I want to find the first cell value of the same row using `Javascript`(no `jquery`). For example if I click on the `return` button on the first row, it should return `ABC`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `closest` to go up and get the element `tr` and then use the function `querySelector` to get the first element `td`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.closest('tr').querySelector('td').textContent.trim());
  });
})
```

```html
<table class='Table1'>  <tr>    <td>      ABC    </td>    <td>      DEF    </td>    <td>      GHI    </td>    <td>      <button class='return'>return</button>    </td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>      JKL    </td>    <td>      MNO    </td>    <td>      PQR    </td>    <td>      <button class='return'>return</button>    </td>  </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

## APIs and Patterns

- **[HTMLTableElement.rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows)** and **[HTMLTableRowElement.cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement#Properties)** for easy table component manipulation.
- **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)** to efficiently control the click event of every tag in the table with only one event listener.
- **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** to reference the button that was clicked, **[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** to reference the table.
- **[`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)** to get the row that the clicked button resided in.
- **[`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)** to determine if **event.target** had a class called `.return`.

---

### Demo

```js
var T = document.querySelector('.Table1');

T.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var out = document.getElementById('out');
  // Clicked tag (i.e. a button.return)
  var tgt = e.target;
  // Tag registered to event (i.e. table.Table1)
  var cur = e.currentTarget;
  // A HTMLCollection of every <tr> in .table1
  var Rows = cur.rows;
  // Declare blank string;
  var txt = "";
  /*
  if clicked tag is NOT .Table1 AND it has class .return...
  */
  if (tgt !== cur && tgt.matches('.return')) {
    /*
    Begin count at 0; keep counting until the last row;
    increment cont by 1
    */
    for (let i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
      // if this row has the clicked button as a descendant...
      if (Rows[i].contains(tgt)) {
        // Get the text of that row's first cell
        txt = Rows[i].cells[0].textContent;
      }
    }
    // Set the value of output#out to extracted text
    out.value = txt;
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

#out {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<output id='out'>&nbsp;</output>
<table class='Table1'>
  <tr>
    <td> ABC </td>
    <td> DEF </td>
    <td> GHI </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> JKL </td>
    <td> MNO </td>
    <td> PQR </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> HHH </td>
    <td> DEF </td>
    <td> GHI </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 123 </td>
    <td> DEF </td>
    <td> GHI </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> XYZ </td>
    <td> DEF </td>
    <td> GHI </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> XXX </td>
    <td> DEF </td>
    <td> GHI </td>
    <td> <button class='return'>return</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```